# Why is my class not being called?

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, uitextfield, uiactionsheet

Every time I exit a textfield, a UIActionsheet is supposed to come up as well as save some information.  when I exit the text field the program exits and the console says its an invalid class called. Why isn't this code working?

```
- (IBAction)classFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender

- (IBAction)classFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender 
                  withActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)typeSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                          initWithFormat:@"%@", indicatedClass];
    labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
    labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
    [greeting release];
    [sender resignFirstResponder];

    typeSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Class types"delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Core Class", @"Elective", nil];
    [typeSheet showInView:self.view];
    [typeSheet release];

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc]       
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 6 times per rotation",     indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 3 times per rotation", indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The action looks fine. Be sure that you have linked the editingDidEnd action in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by implement UITextFieldDelegate protocol in your H file

also I would use the following code - Making sure your textField is connected to the action you wish to run on done (using Interface builder)

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Text Field Delegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if ([textField canResignFirstResponder]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    // add your method here

    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

}
```

Comment: This is my first time programming, so this code doesn't make much sense to me.  When I implemented it, there were a ton of errors.